# xsl:for-each not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I got an XSL variable named filt and it holds data like this

```
<filters>
   <ritem relateditemnumber="8901037" />
   <ritem relateditemnumber="8901038" />
   <ritem relateditemnumber="8901039" />
   <ritem relateditemnumber="8901040" />
</filters>
```

and my for-each loop

```
          <xsl:for-each select="$filt//ritem">
              <textarea>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </textarea>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

I do't know why this is not working every textarea comes as empty.can any one give me a hand in this?

Comment: There might be a possiblity that 'ritem' does not contain any text().

Comment: There is no text in your ritem there is only are attribute. Use: `<xsl:value-of select="@relateditemnumber"/>`

Comment: @hr_117 :thank you for pointing out the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="filt">
    <filters>
      <ritem relateditemnumber="8901037"/>
      <ritem relateditemnumber="8901038"/>
      <ritem relateditemnumber="8901039"/>
      <ritem relateditemnumber="8901040"/>
    </filters>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$filt/filters/ritem">
      <textarea>
        <xsl:value-of select="@relateditemnumber"/>
      </textarea>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get output:

```
<textarea>8901037</textarea>
<textarea>8901038</textarea>
<textarea>8901039</textarea>
<textarea>8901040</textarea>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using to test this?  You can't treat a result tree fragment as a node set like this in true XSLT 1.0.

Comment: So this is not really standard XSLT 1.0. I already started to fear this was a problem of my xlstproc.

Comment: For 'Saxon6.5.5' you may change this stylesheet version="1.0" to stylesheet version="1.1"

Comment: If a question is specifically tagged "xslt-1.0" then it's of limited use to the OP to provide an answer that requires a 2.0 processor.  If you want to include the input inside the stylesheet like this in 1.0 then you can do so by using a `document('')` trick, but it's probably clearer to keep the stylesheet and the input separate.